# How can you control the GPIO pins of an Rpi via flutter?

Tags: python, flutter, dart, bluetooth, raspberry-pi

I have a probably very special question, but I would still be very happy about your help. First things first, I have basic Python and Dart/Flutter skills. For days I have been trying in vain for a solution to connect a Raspbarry Pi (Python) and a smartphone (Flutter). I want to be able to control an LED using a flutter app, so I have to control the GPIO Pins via a Flutter application. I totally don't care whether the connection is established via Bluetooth or the Internet. I can't find any instructions or a tutorial on the internet, so my question is whether you might have found a good video or blog entry on this topic. I would be very happy if you could write me a link to a good explanation in the answer box. It would be even better if someone of you knows how to connect an Rpi and a smartphone and that person could explain it to me. Many many thanks in advance and greetings

Answer (score 1):

Why you don't create a `Websocket/Http_Server` in `Rpi Python` that interacts with the `GPIO` and in other side create another `Websocket/Http_Client` for your `flutter mobile app` and exchange data between them.